# Previous Values Get Overwritten in my List in C#

Tags: c#, list

My previous list value gets overwritten by the new ones I input into my ReadLine().

These is one of my classes.

```
public class Car
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string capacityKg { get; set; }

    public string reachKm { get; set; }

    public string registrationNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I declare my List and Class here:

```
        List<Car> allCars = new List<Car>();

        Car vehicle = new Car();
```

Here is my problem: Everytime I run this code inside my switch statement / do while loop the previous value gets overwritten. For example I input "Car123" the first time I run it and then it outputs Car123 but the second time I add a new value to my list like "car234" it replaces "Car123" with "car234"

```
    vehicle = new Car();

    Write("ID: ");
    vehicle.ID = ReadLine();

    Write("Capacity (kg): ");
    vehicle.capacityKg = ReadLine();

    Write("Reach (km): ");
    vehicle.reachKm = ReadLine();

    Write("Registration number: ");
    vehicle.registrationNumber = ReadLine();

    Clear();

    WriteLine($ "ID: {vehicle.ID}");
    WriteLine($ "Capacity (kg): {vehicle.capacityKg}");
    WriteLine($ "Reach (km): {vehicle.reachKm}");
    WriteLine($ "Registration number: {vehicle.registrationNumber}");

    WriteLine(" ");
    WriteLine("Is this correct? (Y)es (N)o");

    ConsoleKeyInfo yesNo = ReadKey(true);

    // I want to run a code here that checks if the registration number already exists
    if (yesNo.Key == ConsoleKey.Y) {
      allCars.Add(vehicle);

      Clear();

      WriteLine("Delivery unit registered");

      Thread.Sleep(2000);

      Clear();

      break;
    }
    else if (yesNo.Key == ConsoleKey.N) {
      Clear();
    }
    else {
      Clear();

      WriteLine("Invalid key pressed.");

      Thread.Sleep(2000);

      Clear();
    }
```

Comment: Could you try to condense this into a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm not even going to begin reading this copy/pasted wall of text. Please isolate the code that is relevant to the question.

Comment: share Clear() code too and also try to split it to be smaller in order to get help

Comment: This is a great opportunity to start using a debugger to narrow down the problem, stepping through the code one line at a time until you observe an operation which produces an unexpected result.  (For example, the specific operation where you add an element to the list and expect the list to contain two different elements.  The description of the problem suggests that you're adding the same object to the list multiple times, not creating new objects.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you declare your car outside the loop:

```
vehicle = new Car();
```

Then inside the loop you change the car details and add it to the list:

```
do{

  vehicle.Name = Console.ReadLine();
  list.Add(vehicle);

} while ...
```

Because you never make a new object, all you're doing is adding the same car repeatedly to the list, and altering its name, which means after 5 iterations of the loop you will have 1 object in memory (that has had its name changed 5 times), and 6 references pointing to this same object (one is `vehicle` and the other 5 references are `list[0]`, `list[1]` ...)